# VHDL directly comparing vectors

Tags: vector, vhdl, comparator

I was wondering if its possible to directly compare 2 vectors with eachother instead of just looking at them bit by bit.

For example:

```
entity Comparator is
port(a,b in: std_logic_vector (2 downto 0);
     out1, out2 out: std_logic);
end Comparator;

architecture behavioural of Comparator1 is
begin
    if a = b then
        out1 <= '1'
    else if /= then
        out2 <= '1'
    end if;
end behaviour;
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, you can compare two array types of the same type and subtype indication directly.

However your example code isn't valid.

The result of the expression `a=b` is boolean.  You convert that to std_logic by assigning `out1` and `out2`.  An if statement in this context has to be in a process statement.  Also you don't need two outputs:

```
architecture foo of Comparator1 is
begin
UNLABELED:
    process (a,b)
    begin
        if a = b then
            out1 <= '1';
        else 
            out1 <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Alternative a concurrent signal assignment statement, a conditional signal assignment that has an equivalent process to that above:

```
architecture fum of Comparator1 is
begin
UNLABELED:
    out1 <= '1' when a = b else '0';
end architecture;
```

Comment: I think this is only valid in  VHDL-2008 :/

Comment: @mikelsr your thinking is incorrect. The concurrent conditional signal assignment statement (as shown) is supported in the original -1987 standard and following revisions. The sequential conditional signal assignment statement was introduced -2008. Both architectures were validated using -1993.

Comment: @user1155120 my bad

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `to_integer(unsigned(a))` and threat them as integers.
For example:

```
IF(to_integer(unsigned(a)) < to_integer(unsigned(b))) THEN
```

Comment: Here's a question, why bother with to_integer? Can't I just do this:
IF(unsigned(a) < unsigned(b)) THEN  ? What happens here? Genuinely curious.

Comment: @nirvanaswap Related to [this link](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/reference/std_logic/arith/comp.html) you can compare only compare `std_logic_unsigned` or `std_logic_signed`. Assuming that `unsigned(...)` cast the type properly just using `unsigned(...)` (or `signed(...)`) should work as well.