# Comparing two bit_vectors without boolean logic

Tags: vhdl

Let's say I want to write a 2bit comparator in VHDL.

There's a vector a and vector b.

Does comparing vectors like

```
(a=b)
```

With an approach like this:

```
library ieee;

entity comp is port(
a,b: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
a_eq_b; out bit);

architecture behav of comp is
   begin
   a_eq_b <= '1' when (a=b) 
           else '0';
end of behav;
```

work? Or would I have to get the minterms via truth table and do it with boolean logic?

cheers

**EDIT1:**

```
library ieee;

entity comp is port(
a,b: in bit_vector(1 downto 0);
a_eq_b: out bit);
end comp;

architecture behav of comp is
  begin
  a_eq_b <= a=b;
end behav;
```

Comment: Why don't you try compiling/simulating your description and check the results?

Comment: Don't have access to an ide at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL directly comparing vectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23877501/vhdl-directly-comparing-vectors)

Comment: The equality operator "=" returns a Boolean value TRUE or FALSE when evaluating the condition `a = b` (the parentheses aren't needed here). That Boolean value is used to conditionally assign a '1' or a '0' to `a_eq_b`. There's an error in you a_eq_b port assignment (a semicolon instead of a colon).  Your also missing an end for your entity declaration. Another error in architecture end (remove the `of`). After these three fixes your code analyzes, elaborates and simulates.

Comment: cheers, edited the original post. Would it be correct this way?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 1**: Yes, you can compare two array types of the same type directly.

Follow below a test bench and its result for your VHDL description.

**Waveform**

[image: Waveform for <code>comp</code> entity]

**tb.v**

```
 library IEEE;

 entity tb is
 end tb;

 architecture behav of tb is
   signal a : bit_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";
   signal b : bit_vector(1 downto 0) := "00";
   signal a_eq_b : bit;
 begin
   dut: entity work.comp port map (a=>a, b=>b, a_eq_b=>a_eq_b );
   stimulus: process
   begin
     wait for 10 ns;
     a <= "01";
     wait for 10 ns;
     b <= "01";
     wait for 10 ns;
     a <= "10";
     wait for 10 ns;
     b <= "11";
     wait for 10 ns;
     b <= "10";
     wait;
   end process stimulus;

 end behav;
```

**Edit 2**: 
You can use the `=` operator to control your output assignment: `a_eq_b1 <= '1' when (a = b) else '0';`, but you cannot directly assign the result from the equality operator `=`, which returns a boolean, to a `bit`.

Let me know if you are looking for something in specific, as your question only asks for a "would it work or not answer".

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it actually said "yes" or "no".

Comment: Also not really what i was looking for. Question was if it's possible to compare two vectors with = operator.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vhdl 2008, you can use the matching relation operators, as they return the source type (bit or std_ulogic), rather than a boolean.

```
a_eq_b <= (a ?= b);
```

it is equivalent to

```
a_eq_b <= a <= '1' when a = b else '0';
```